# Output of all the Armstrong numbers in the range from 1 to Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm dealing with a task: I have to write a method to find all the Armstrong numbers from 1 to N.

> In number theory, an Armstrong number number (also known as a narcissistic number, a pluperfect digital invariant (PPDI), or a plus perfect number) in a given number base b is a number that is the sum of its own digits each raised to the power of the number of digits. **¹**

This code works if N < 1000000000, but if I'm trying Long.MAX_VALUE - the program even doesn't finish work. I understand that the problem is that I'm trying to check all the numbers, and it's too long.

I don't know what else I can do.

```
public class Solution {
    static List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();
    static int[][] powers;

    public static long[] getNumbers(long N) {
        fillPowers();
        if(N <= 0) {
            return new long[0];
        }
        list.clear();
        long res = 0L;
        for (long i = 1L; i < N; i++) {
            int t = getDigitFromLong(i);
            long temp = i;
            while (temp >= 1) {
                long devidedIntoTen = temp % 10;
                res += powers[t] [(int) devidedIntoTen];
                temp/=10;
            }
            if(res == i) {
                list.add(res);
                res = 0;
            } else {
                res = 0;
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(list);
        long[] l = new long[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            l[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return l;
    }

    public static void fillPowers() {
        int numDigits = getDigitFromLong(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        powers = new int[numDigits][10];

        for (int i = 0; i < numDigits; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                powers[i][j] = (int) Math.pow(j, i);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getDigitFromLong (long number) {
        int numDigits = 0;
        while (number > 0) {
            number /= 10;
            numDigits++;
        }
        return numDigits;
    }

}
```

I've created the matrix with the powers of numbers so as not to waste resources on counting them every iteration.

I also tried to write the permutations of the numbers that I've found to skip them in my loop. But still, it's too long and ineffective.

And I have no clue what else I can do. I would appreciate a lot if you could give me an idea.

---

<sub>**1** [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissistic_number)</sub>

Comment: What about parallelizing it? Get the input, divide it in N (N=number of processors) clusters, run this in parallel. Also (I didn't know what Armstrong number was) "An Armstrong number is one whose sum of digits raised to the power /three/ of number of  digits equals the number itself" it looks you have too many loops to find this? get the number, split into chars, raise each to power of count of chars, sum them all, check with original number... this only requires a single loop ? (Sorry I'm no mathematician)

Comment: If it is a matter of the program working, except it takes too long, would it be a candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ?  ( I don't know. I'm not that familiar with Code Review, so I really am asking. )

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I really tried several options: using String to find the length, and elevation of numbers to a power in one loop - the result is, unfortunately, the same: too long on big numbers. I'm sure there is an algorithm for this task, but I haven't found it yet)) And thanks for giving the link on Code Review - I didn't know about it, so I'll check.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A005188

Comment: By the way, it won't help you, but one way to find the number of digits in a number is to use a logarithm:  `int length = (int)Math.floor(Math.log10((double) n) + 1);`

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Use it quite often. But I believe  `(int)Math.log10(n)+1` is sufficient where `n` is a `long`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and the tips on how to improve my code!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of iterating over all possible integer numbers, let's iterate over all possible sequences

```
a1^n + a2^n + a3^n +  .. + an^n = A, where 0 ≤ ai ≤ 9
```

and checking corresponding sums A for "Armstrongeness".

As sum is commutative (a+b = b+a) we need to iterate only over non-decreasing sequences:

```
a1^n ≤ a2^n ≤ a3^n ≤  .. ≤ an^n
```

For example, lets find all 3-digit Armstrong numbers:

```
0^3 + 0^3 + 0^3 = 0
0^3 + 0^3 + 1^3 = 1
0^3 + 0^3 + 2^3 = 8
...
0^3 + 3^3 + 6^3 = 243
0^3 + 3^3 + 7^3 = 370 <--  Armstrong number
0^3 + 3^3 + 8^3 = 539
...
0^3 + 4^3 + 6^3 = 280
0^3 + 4^3 + 7^3 = 407 <-- Armstrong number
0^3 + 4^3 + 8^3 = 576
...
1^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 = 92
1^3 + 3^3 + 5^3 = 153 <-- Armstrong number
1^3 + 3^3 + 6^3 = 244
1^3 + 3^3 + 7^3 = 371 <-- Armstrong number
1^3 + 3^3 + 8^3 = 540
...
9^3 + 9^3 + 9^3 = 2187
```

There is 900 3-digit numbers, but only 178 possible 3-digit permutations. Does not sound like big deal, however for 900'000'000'000'000'000 18-digit numbers, there is only 4'515'854 permutations.

Algorithm complexity is `10^N / N!`, still exponential, but drastically faster than initial  `10^N` solution.

My written on Java implementation computes all numbers by ~2 sec on my machine:

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    private static int[] digits;
    private static long sumOfPows = 0;
    private static long[] pows;
    private static long min = 0;
    private static long max = 0;
    private static List<Long> result = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int numOfDigits = 1; numOfDigits <= 19 ; numOfDigits++) {
            search(numOfDigits);
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }


    private static void search(int numOfDigits) {
        digits = new int[numOfDigits];
        sumOfPows = 0;
        pows = new long[10];
        min = powerN(10, numOfDigits-1);
        max = powerN(10, numOfDigits);
        if (max < 0) { // check for overflow
            max = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pows.length; i++) {
            pows[i] = powerN(i, numOfDigits);
        }
        searchRecursively(0);
    }


    private static void searchRecursively(int i) {
        if (i == digits.length) {
            // sequence fully constructed, lets test it for "Armstrongeness"
            if (min <= sumOfPows && sumOfPows < max) { // check for right number of digits
                if (isArmstrong(digits, sumOfPows)) {
                    result.add(sumOfPows);
                }
            }
        } else {
            // we have a_1, a_2, a_(i-1) sequence, let's construct next a_i member
            // a_i should be in interval [a_(i-1)..9] or in interval [0..9] if i=0
            int minDigit = i > 0 ? digits[i-1] : 0;
            for (int j = minDigit; j <= 9; j++) {
                digits[i] = j;
                sumOfPows += pows[j];
                if (sumOfPows >= 0 && sumOfPows < max) { // check for overflow
                    searchRecursively(i + 1);
                }
                sumOfPows -= pows[j]; // backtracking
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isArmstrong(int[] digits, long sumOfPows) {
        int[] digitsSorted = toDigits(sumOfPows, digits.length);
        return Arrays.equals(digits, digitsSorted);
    }

    private static int[] toDigits(long num, int len) {
        int[] result = new int[len];
        while(num > 0) {
            result[--len] = (int)(num % 10);
            num /= 10;
        }
        Arrays.sort(result);
        return result;
    }

    private static long powerN(int number, int power){
        long res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
            res *= number;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, yes, that is it! You helped me a lot. And thank you for the comments, now I can understand how it works!

Comment: Very nice! +1: But there's a lot more to this algorithm than just noticing the permutations of digit runs of the same length result in the same sum. You should really provide more detail for those that search this site.

Comment: @WJS, Tried to write more detailed answer, but was blocked by "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code." warning. Looks like StackOverflow punishes authors for long answers.

Comment: no there are much much longer answers than this

Comment: @WJS I have updated my answer, hope now is clearer

Comment: @phucls tried to format formulas with <sub><sup> but looks like SO does not accept that.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov thank you for your explanation, you are right

Comment: @Viktor it does, just not in code blocks, so if code formatting is required then you need to put into `<code><pre>`, otherwise just use in blockquote format

Answer (score 2):

> This code works if N < 1000000000, but if I'm trying Long.MAX_VALUE - the program even doesn't finish work.

And it never will, at least not in a reasonable amount of time unless you find a significant mathematical shortcut and/or use a fast processor with sufficient number of cores, or some combination of all three.

Assume that you can iterate from `1 to Long.MAX_VALUE` and test each value as an Armstrong number in one picosecond (i.e. 1/1e12 of a second) which is highly optimistic.

```
long days = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toDays(Long.MAX_VALUE/1000);
System.out.println(days);
```

prints

```
106
```

It would take just over 106 days to finish the computation using a single thread.

**Interesting Factoid**

From [Math Lair](https://mathlair.allfunandgames.ca/armstrong.php)

> There are only 89 Armstrong numbers in total. The largest Armstrong number is 115,132,219,018,763,992,565,095,597,973,971,522,401, which has 39 digits. It has been proven that there are no Armstrong numbers with more than 39 digits.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... And I have no clue what else I can do. I would appreciate a lot if you could give me an idea. ..."*

You can try using a *[parallel stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html)*, although the performance increase is negligible.

```java
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(1, (int) 1e5)
         .parallel()
         .forEachOrdered(
             x -> {
                 if (plusPerfect(String.valueOf(x)))
                     list.add(String.valueOf(x));
             });
```

```java
boolean plusPerfect(String n) {
    int m = n.length();
    BigInteger x = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (char c : n.toCharArray())
        x = x.add(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(c)).pow(m));
    return n.equals(x.toString());
}
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 153, 370, 371, 407, 1634, 8208, 9474, 54748, 92727, 93084]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this advice, I'm not yet used to the parallel stream, so it's a good chance for me to practice))